# Проблема с циклом с большим объемом данных

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

Добрый день. У меня есть массив `int[]` размер `60480`, для удобства мне нужно раскидать данные по 7 "ячейкам", для этого я использую конструкцию `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> week_history` (есть подозрение, что это не правильное решение с точки зрения производительности и т.д., но это не точно).

**Собственно проблема:** Я раскидываю данные по 7 спискам и помещаю их в один общий список. Далее после этого, я хочу проверить в логах содержимое моего массива, но там выводится некорректные данные(такое впечатление, что некоторые ячейки перезаписываются друг на друга). В чём моя ошибка? Есть подозрение, что алгоритм по распределению данных по спискам не успевает завершиться, а я уже начинаю выводить в лог?

Код:

```
        ArrayList<Integer> dayHistory = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> week_history = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < history_array.length; i++, j++){

            dayHistory.add(history_array[i]);

            if (j == 8639){
                j = 0;
             week_history.add(dayHistory);
                dayHistory.clear();

            }

            if (i == (history_array.length - 1)){
                Log.w("LOG_TAG", "Закончили цикл");
            }
        }

        Log.w("LOG_TAG", "Переходим на след цикл");

        for (int i = 0; i < week_history.get(1).size(); i++){
            Log.wtf("LOG_TAG", "Элемент [" + i + "] - " + week_history.get(1).get(i));
        }
```

Comment: Странный алгоритм распределения. Подумайте, как можно переписать проще. Насчет вопроса про то, что не успевает записаться: все успевает, у вас не многопоточное приложение, все выполняется синхронно сверху вниз. Так что ошибка в алгоритме, а не в том, что данных много (к слову массив из 60480 элементов относительно небольшой).

Comment: не сильно разбираюсь в java, но если ArrayList организован так же как List в C#, то у вас в `week_history` во всех "ячейках" будет одинаковое значение, то, которое вы записали последним. Всё дело в том, что подобный список - ссылочный тип, и в `week_history` записывается не значение списка, а ссылка на него, соответственно командой `dayHistory.clear();` вы уничтожаете данные во всех ячейках, куда уже добавили `dayHistory`

Comment: @qzavyer Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Не?

```
int[][] weekHistory = new int[7][8640];
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 8640; j++){
        weekHistory[i][j] = history_array[i * 8640 + j];
    }
}
```